# Netlogo: Stop a turtle in route and make others assuming

Tags: netlogo

I create 3 cars, but I only have routes for the car with ID 0 and 1:

Car 0 -> route [4 3]

Car 1 -> route [7 6 5]

Car 2 -> route [] because I want this car stopped and it's spare

I want create a **crash?** variable for the cars, ie, **IF** reach 25 ticks, the variable crash? It is **TRUE**, and one of the cars in route stops ...

In my go procedure i try put this, but one-of only :

```
to go
ask carr with [ not route-complete? and not crash?] [
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   if route = [] [
  set target spawn-target
  ]
  if target = nobody [
  set target item route-counter route
  ]
  face target
  ifelse distance target > 1 [
  fd 1
  ] [
  move-to target
   ifelse target != spawn-target [
    set route-counter route-counter + 1
  ] [
    set route-complete? true
  ]
  set target nobody
  ]
  if route-counter > length route - 1 [
  set route-counter 0
  set target spawn-target
  ]
  ]
  tick
  end
```

I should only stop **one-of** the cars that has a route and not count the car with ID 2 that has already stopped. 
because I think this code accounts for all the cars and choose one to stop, but I want to just stop or the car 0 or 1.
How to fix?

Then, how can I define a car to be the spare car (car with ID 2) to take the stopped car route to visit the missing homes?
Because at 25 ticks if one of the cars 0 or 1 stop, there will surely be houses that have not been visited ...

If anyone can help me in two tasks that can not develop, would greatly. Thank you

Comment: Hi @LukeC, I hope you are well. If you could get a look at my problem, it would be awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easiest might be to just get the car that 'crashes' to pass on the remainder of its route on to the spare car using `sublist` to index the `route` variable- check out the [dictionary definition](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#subliststring) for more detail on that. In the interest of changing your code as little as possible, try inserting the following code right at the beginning of your `go` procedure (code comments give more detail, full `go` procedure below):

```
to go
  ; only run this chunk if ticks = 25
  if ticks = 25 [
    ask one-of carr with [ not crash? and not route-complete? ] [
      ; get one of the still moving cars to:
      ; set crash? to true, change color to yellow
      ; for easy visibility
      set crash? true
      set color yellow
      ; make a temporary variable to hold the remaining house
      ; targets using sublist
      let remaining-route sublist route route-counter ( length route )
      ask one-of carr with [ route = [] ] [
        ; have the 'spare' care take over the remaining-route,
        ; set route-complete to false, and set the current
        ; target to 'nobody' so that the other conditions for
        ; movement are satisfied
        set route remaining-route
        set route-complete? false
        set target nobody
      ]
    ]
  ]


  ;; ask carr with route-complete set to false
  ask carr with [ not route-complete? and not crash? ] [
    ;for the spare car not to move
    if route = [] [
      set target spawn-target
    ]
    if target = nobody [
      set target item route-counter route
    ]

    face target
    ifelse distance target > 1 [
      fd 1
    ] [
      move-to target
      ifelse target != spawn-target [
        set route-counter route-counter + 1
      ] [
        set route-complete? true
      ]
      set target nobody
    ]
    ;; If the route counter would index outside of the
    ; list boundaries, reset it to 0
    if route-counter > length route - 1 [
      set route-counter 0
      set target spawn-target
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Note that as-is, the active `carr` can technically (rarely) complete their route before `ticks` = 25. To avoid this, either stop the model when the routes are complete or work around some other way.

Comment: Thanks @LukeC, I have already updated your changes, however often it gives error ("I think expected input to be an agent or agentset but got nobody instead").

    Line- ask one-of carr with [ route = [] ] [
 I think it is sometimes the car that stops, can be the one that has no route, ie the spare car. What do you think it could be?

Comment: I think the mistake is: at 25 ticks a car needs to have its full route, then the other car stops and the spare car visits the missing homes. what happens is that most of the time, none of the cars completes your visits until the number of ticks, and then the code gives error ... Is it better to increase the number of ticks?

Comment: I copied exactly your chunk example at the beginning of my go procedure and modified the ask carr as you said. I will put my go full procedure on the question to compare. I was wrong on something?

Comment: @MarceloAlves- I think I see the error now, I forgot to tell you to remove the `ask carr...` bit. I've posted the complete `go` procedure with the edits... sorry about that!

Comment: I always have this error, because no car finishes its route. for once it worked, because I realized that the houses are close enough together and then one car ended the route and the other stopped ... but it almost always makes a mistake..., that is, in your case if the houses are together gives an error, in my case it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163366/discussion-between-luke-c-and-marcelo-alves).